# Docusign API Authentication for Captive Recipient

Tags: authentication, docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out the correct authentication pattern to use for Docusign for captive users on my site. The users have already authed on my site, and probably don't have Docusign accounts. I'm using the Docusign C# SDK's running on the server to get the Url for embedded signing. To create the envelope, I am currently sending an auth token generate by the user signing in to Docusign, but then they have to either have or create Docusign accounts.

If I don't want the users to have to sign in to Docusign, what is the proper way to authenticate the service to the Docusign API host?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/), then yes, you will have to [use refresh tokens](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#using-refresh-tokens) and then even these eventually expire.

If you use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), you only need to get consent once per-user (or use [administrative consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-external/) for entire account) and then you won't need to have user log again or do anything again to obtain new access token ever.

**Note:** your end-users don't need to have DocuSign accounts, or consent or any of that. The sender will be the same fixed account you used to auth with JWT and you already consented to.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I'm not sure JWT's are the way to go either, since the users are not part of any particular domain (this is a B2C app), and I have no need for offline access to the tokens. Just need to have them sign a liability waiver once, and then be done. In some documents I saw this referred to as a "Captive Registration". In other systems (like Google Maps), I could use an api client id and a secret, and just use the service. Was ho[ping for that type of approach somehow. Maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: Your users do not need to have a DocuSign account in order to sign documents, hence they don't need to log in.